# XSLT adding information in columns to HTML table instead of rows

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-table

I've been given this XML code and I'm supposed to transform that into a traditional HTML timetable with day names on the top row and times on the right. It becomes so tricky for me when I try to write the rows for each time. By the way, don't consider the attribute priority. Could anyone please help me with this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<timetable>
   <day>
      <numday>1</numday>
      <task priority="medium">
          <time-sta>12</time-sta>
          <time-end>14</time-end>
          <name>Tutorías</name>
      </task>
   </day>
   <day>
       <numday>2</numday>
       <task priority="high">
           <time-sta>12</time-sta>
           <time-end>14</time-end>
           <name>Autómatas</name>
       </task>
   </day>
   <day>
       <numday>4</numday>
       <task priority="high">
           <time-sta>9</time-sta>
           <time-end>11</time-end>
           <name>Procesadores de lenguajes</name>
       </task>
       <task>
           <time-sta>16</time-sta>
           <time-end>17</time-end>
           <name>Matemática Discreta </name>
       </task>
   </day>
   <day>
       <numday>3</numday>
       <task priority="high">
           <time-sta>9</time-sta>
           <time-end>11</time-end>
           <name>Procesadores de lenguajes</name>
       </task>
   </day>
   <day>
       <numday>5</numday>
       <task priority="low">
           <time-sta>17</time-sta>
           <time-end>18</time-end>
           <name>Ver la tele</name>
       </task>
   </day>
</timetable>
```

The output required if possible should be the next html table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Time/Day</th>
        <th>Monday</th>
        <th>Tuesday</th>
        <th>Wednesday</th>
        <th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9:00 - 10:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td rowspan="2">Procesadores de lenguajes</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Procesadores de lenguajes</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10:00 - 11:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>11:00 - 12:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12:00 - 13:00</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Tutorías</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Autómatas</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>13:00 - 14:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>14:00 - 15:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>15:00 - 16:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>16:00 - 17:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Matemática Discreta</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>17:00 - 18:00</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Ver la tele</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to get that output with the xml given or is it needed that each of the nodes had at least tags for defining all the periods of times in the timetable even if they're empty?

Comment: You can use xslt extension function with Java or C# ...

Comment: Yes, I know, the problem here is to do it only with xslt.

Comment: All what you need to get the day name from the time-sta considering that this element holds the day index of the current month.

Comment: Not sure what "a traditional HTML timetable" means in this case. Could you post the required output of your example? And what if there are multiple tasks in the same time slot?

Comment: well, I think the numday field is the equivalent for mon-fri day of the week. The output should be a timetable with the top row cells heading for mon-fri and the first column for hours 9, 10, 11... There are not supposed to be overlapping tasks.

Comment: The problem is that only the day-time matching cells of the table have to contain the name of the task. The rest of cells of the table should be empty.

Comment: You are not answering my question about the required output. It seems additional input required here, not contained in the XML source, and that is the (constant) time slots each day should display, whether empty or not.

Comment: would you please draw the required output on image ?!

Comment: @MuhammadHamed No, not an image. **Code**.

Comment: Shall the rows will represent the time from start to end ? what if there are a conflict .. shall be the slot from 9 to 11 take three vertical cells with the same name or they should be merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not quite simple. Generating the table based on two constants (9 hours by 5 days) is fairly trivial. Looking up the task that belongs to each cell is not too difficult either - you just need to match the current cell's column and row to the task's day and starting hour. The tricky part is skipping the cells that are made redundant by previous tasks in the same day overflowing to subsequent time-slots.

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="task" match="task" use="concat(../numday, '|', time-sta)" />
<xsl:key name="task-by-day" match="task" use="../numday" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Time/Day</th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:call-template name="rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="start-row" select="9"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="end-row" select="17"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="rows">
    <xsl:param name="start-row"/>
    <xsl:param name="end-row"/>

        <tr>
            <th><xsl:value-of select="$start-row"/></th>
            <xsl:call-template name="cols">
                <xsl:with-param name="current-row" select="$start-row"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="start-col" select="1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="end-col" select="5"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </tr>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:if test="$start-row &lt; $end-row">
            <xsl:call-template name="rows">
                <xsl:with-param name="start-row" select="$start-row + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="end-row" select="$end-row"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="cols">
    <xsl:param name="current-row"/>
    <xsl:param name="start-col"/>
    <xsl:param name="end-col"/>

    <xsl:variable name="task" select="key('task', concat($start-col, '|', $current-row))" />
    <xsl:variable name="overlap-tasks" select="key('task-by-day', $start-col)[time-sta &lt; $current-row and time-end > $current-row]" />

    <xsl:if test="not($overlap-tasks)">
        <td rowspan="{$task/time-end - $task/time-sta}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$task/name"/>
        </td>
    </xsl:if>
    <!-- recursive call -->
    <xsl:if test="$start-col &lt; $end-col">
        <xsl:call-template name="cols">
            <xsl:with-param name="current-row" select="$current-row"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="start-col" select="$start-col + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="end-col" select="$end-col"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example input, will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Time/Day</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>9</th>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="2">Procesadores de lenguajes</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Procesadores de lenguajes</td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>10</th>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>11</th>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>12</th>
    <td rowspan="2">Tutorías</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Autómatas</td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>13</th>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>14</th>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>15</th>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>16</th>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="1">Matemática Discreta </td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>17</th>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="NaN"></td>
    <td rowspan="1">Ver la tele</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

which renders as:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that was awesome. I can see that this solution was really out of reach for me and my beginner knowledge, but this has opened my eyes to see what you really can do with this XSLT. Thank you very much for this great solution.

Comment: @user3554818 Actually, this is not the best example of what you can do with XSLT. Basically, it's just a *procedural* i,j loop with a twist. Where XSLT really shines is in its *declarative* programming tools - enabling the processing of XML documents with varying depths of hierarchy with minimum effort.

Comment: @nichael.hor257k could you please lead me to a practical example in which I can see how really powerful this tool is? I want to learn learn learn... I'm so glad that I met parameters, variables and keys yesterday

Comment: @user3554818 I am sorry, there are so many I wouldn't know where to start. Why don't you stick around and follow the XSLT tag and/or explore previous posts under the same tag; I am sure you will learn a lot (I know I have).

Comment: What if I wanted to use the attribute priority to decide which of many overlapping tasks it should show? I'm trying to do this, but it's driving me really crazy...

Comment: Did you not say there won't be any overlapping tasks?

Comment: Yesss )) but you know, after the path you showed me I started to wonder and wonder... I don't want to bother you but now I'm not able to sort it out by myself :/ and you're very good at this... any ideas?

Comment: There's a reason why I asked about this right from start. This is already quite difficult, and choosing from among overlapping tasks would make it **much** more so. Each task's display depends on the previous tasks of the same day - and these tasks are not known until they have been selected by their priority. You would have to make a preliminary pass to eliminate the conflicting tasks, and then apply the above to the remaining ones.

Comment: So, do I have to make the preliminary pass transforming my xml to another xml file and then transforming this one with what we used before? Or is there a way to do both steps in the same transformation?

Comment: It should be sufficient to make the preliminary pass into a variable.